# What is the C++ iterator for STL Queue?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, queue

I know we can not iterate easily in STL Queue, but I want to do something like this:

```
void myFun(Node* root) {
    queue<pair<int, Node*>> myQueue;
    myQueue.push(make_pair(0, root));
    auto it = myQueue.front();
}
```

This works, however, what should I use instead of the `auto` keyword for the queues?

We use something like this for maps:

```
map<int, Node*>::iterator it = myMap.begin();
```

But

```
queue<pair<int, Node*>>::iterator it = myQueue.front();
```

This does not work and throws error:

```
‘iterator’ is not a member of ‘std::queue<std::pair<int, Node*> >’
queue<pair<int, Node*>>::iterator it = myQueue.front();
```

What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

The [front](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/front) member of `std::queue` doesn't return an iterator at all, it returns a reference to the first element in the queue. So `auto` would just be the type inside the queue

```
std::pair<int, Node*> it = myQueue.front();
```

This makes a copy of the element, but you can also take a reference, or a const reference, to that element.

As there are no `queue` member functions that return an iterator, you'll have to look at all the elements with a sequence of `front` and `pop` calls.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pair<int, Node*> &`, (possibly const) since that's what `front()` returns. None of the containers (or container adaptors) have a `front()` method that returns an iterator.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

`std::queue` does not provide access to its internals. It's interface is that of a queue: you push elements into it, and you pop elements out of it. That's all. If you need a container that lets you look at its contents, `std::queued isn't the appropriate choice.